# How to recognize mathematical symbols using recognizer classes?

Tags: c#, wpf, tablet-pc, handwriting

I am doing a project for tablet based pc's where the user would write an equation to be solved.

The problem is that the recognizer classes that I am using, [`InkAnalyzer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.ink.inkanalyzer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), cannot recognize root signs or any other mathematical signs that I input. Is there someway for me to add such functionality?

Basically, I want my program to function much like the math Input Panel that comes with windows 7. Oh, and I code in c#.

Comment: you need just to recognize the chars that are mathematical ? you can use regular expression for this

Comment: what do you mean? when i make a root sign, the recognizer converts it to either "Other" or a question mark (guess it looks the same). I need to convert the input the user writes to a computer root sign, but i don't know how to enable the recognizer to do this... ;)

Comment: Haha, thanks BalamBalam, but your comment isn't really useful. I know that I need to find a way to add maths character sets, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it's not what you want to hear but basically you can't do this. At least not without insider help at Microsoft. In order to facilitate this, you would need to develop your own language recognizer. And as far as I know, the tools and documentation for doing so are not provided to third parties.

However, you could develop your own recognition system that utilizes the existing ink collection and stroke model provided by the `System.Windows.Ink` API's, but it would not plug into the `InkAnalyzer` model. Utilizing the stroke information will yield much better results than a simple OCR type of system where you're simply analyzing shapes.

It would have been very useful for Microsoft to expose their math parsing capabilities in the System.Windows.Ink namespace but as that was coming out, Microsoft was giving up on tablets. Then the iPad came along and ate their lunch and now who knows if we'll ever see a focus on ink input again.

Answer (score 2):

[Load ink to a MathInputControl in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693469/load-ink-to-a-mathinputcontrol-in-c-sharp)

The solution provided in the page discusses how to program Math Input Control.

Once you have your math eqn in the form of strokes loaded (you can get them from InkCanvas Control - if you dont plan to read it from elsewhere and construct strokes) into Math Input Control through StylusPointCollection and store them into StrokeCollection class and stream it into an ISF (Ink Serialized Format) file.

The solution author supplies ISF file to Math Input Control. And some more work is involved to get back the solution - before that managing the Math Input window etc,.