# Saving ink from a MathInputControl

Tags: c++, windows, microsoft-ink

I'm using a `MathInputControl` to receive handwritten input for the steps involved in solving a math exercise. I'd like to allow the user to go back to a previous step in the solution and edit the input for that step. `MathInputControl` [allows loading previously saved ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693469/load-ink-to-a-mathinputcontrol-in-c-sharp), but it doesn't provide a way to save it.

I can receive its processed output (in MathML) by handling the Insert event, but I can't recover the user's handwriting from that.

I tried `QueryInterface`-ing to an `IInkPicture`, `IInkEdit` or an `IInkCollector` that allow saving ink, but `MathInputControl` doesn't implement any of them.

Concretely, is there a way to save a user's handwriting from a `MathInputControl` (in addition to receiving the MathML output) ?

Comment: I'm 98% sure this is not possible.  It only implements the IMathInputControl interface.  LoadInk() does not keep a reference to the passed IInkDisp*.  Cranky control.